# How to show checkboxes to user that are saved as yes in database at frontend?

Tags: c#, html, checkbox

This is my grid which is dynamic. It is saving customer description against each checkbox. That is, if I mark the checkbox against Individual then it saves Y in my database otherwise N. so Now I just want to show tick on checkboxes that are saved Y in the database. Below is the code for my dynamic grid:

```
  public string getCustomerStateGrid()
    {
        string html = ""; int Count = 1;



        DataTable dt = getDataTableFromQuery(@"select Id,cuscheckbox,CustomerDescription from CustomerState3");
        html = "<h2>    Customer State </h2><br/><table class=\"display unbreakable\" id=\"tblCustomerDetail\" style=\"width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;\"><thead>";

        #region Header

        html += "<tr><th height='40' class=\"Greyheader\" style=\"width:5%\">S.No</th>";
        html += "<th height='40' class=\"Greyheader\" style=\"width:30%\">Customer Status</th>";

        html += "<th height='40' class=\"Greyheader\" style=\"width:15%\">Customer Description</th>";

        //html += "<th class=\"Greyheader\" style=\"width:12%\">Action</th>";
        html += "</tr></thead>";

        #endregion

        #region Body
        html += "<tbody>";
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                html += "<tr class=\"GreyBorder\" id='tblCustomerDetail_" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "' pkid=\"" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "\"  class=\"DataRow\">";
                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" style=\"text-align:center !important;\">" + Count + "</td>";


                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\"><input  id='txtcuscheckbox_" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "' type=\"checkbox\" style=\" text-align: right; width:95;\" value='" + dr["cuscheckbox"].ToString() + "' class=\"mediumTextField Customer Status\" /></td>";
              html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\"><input  id='txtCustomerDescription_" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "' type=\"textbox\" style=\" text-align: right; width:95;\" value='" + dr["CustomerDescription"].ToString() + "' class=\"mediumTextField Customer Description\" /></td>";


                html += "</tr>";
                Count++;


            }
        }
        else
        {


            html += "<tr class=\"GreyBorder\" ><td style=\"text-align:center !important;\" class=\"GreyBorder\"  colspan='6'>No Data.</td></tr>";

            html += "</tr>";
        }

        html += "</tbody>";

        #endregion

        html += "<tfoot><tr class='GreyBorder'>";

        html += "<td class='GreyBorder' colspan='2'></td> ";
        html += "</tr></tfoot>";

        html += "</table><br/>";


        return html.ToString();

    }
```

I just want to customize this line of code

```
           html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\"><input  
      id='txtcuscheckbox_" + dr["Id"].ToString() + "' 
       type=\"checkbox\" 
      style=\" text-align: right; width:95;\" value='" + d 
      dr["cuscheckbox"].ToString() + "' class=\"mediumTextField 
      Customer Status\" /></td>";
```

so that it shows tick on checkbox. Can anyone modify my code to achieve this result? Is there any way we can do using ternary operator?
[image]

Comment: Are you working with ASP.NET?

Comment: yes I am working with asp.net

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Well in essence you need:

```
var isChecked = 'Y';
html += isChecked == 'Y' ? "<input type=\"checkbox\" checked>" : "<input type=\"checkbox\">";
```

However, you are mixing front-end with back-end logic. Wouldnt it better to create a JSON endpoint that returns the data to the front-end and have the front-end generate the HTML?

EDIT:

To modify the current logic you could replace the line for creating the textbox with something like this:

```
var isChecked = dr["cuscheckbox"].ToString().ToUpper() == "Y" ? "checked" : string.Empty;
html += $"<td class=\"GreyBorder\"><input  id='txtcuscheckbox_{dr["Id"].ToString()}' type=\"checkbox\" style=\" text-align: right; width:95;\" class=\"mediumTextField Customer Status\" {isChecked}/></td>";
```

Comment: I added these two lines of code but its still showing all my checkboxes empty.

Comment: I am new at this so I really dont know if we can do this through json. But I need to modify my own code to achieve my result.

Comment: That is because i gave an example, and not a modification for your code. Step 1 would be to change your query to actually return the value (Y or N), step 2 is to modify the line where the checkbox is created to work with similar logic as i posted.

Comment: Can you modify my code please? As i am still confused

Comment: What is the fieldname to get the Y or N value from the database?

Comment: cuscheckbox is the field name for checkbox in database

Comment: cuscheckbox = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked') == true ? "Y" : "N";       This is how I am accessing this field

Comment: Then please update the origional question with what 'isnt working' means. Do you get an error?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But the checkboxes should show checked at the front end. They are still empty.

Comment: Inspect the HTML, what is being generated? Debug the code, what is the value of dr["cuscheckbox"] inside the foreach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206690/discussion-between-rutaba-and-roel-abspoel).